# Convert google analytics, tag manager in an existing CMS site into gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am currently converting a drupal module into gatsby. In this module I have many scripts like google analytics, tag manager, facebook pixel and more.

**What is a good approach to integrate them into Gatsby?**

some scripts contain a reference to script files, noscript tags and iframe tags, which I can't use in JSX straight away

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-analytics/

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager/

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-facebook-pixel/

Comment: Thanks for these info, there are 9 other scripts (not popular) need to included some of the scripts accompany iframe or no-script tags also. My concern is about them

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.